# Making $f$ differentiable

Tags: limits, derivatives

Given the following function
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} a+e^{x-1}, & x<1 \\ bx^{2}+1, x\geq1 \end{array}\right.$$
I have to find the values of $a$ and $b$ such that $f$ is differentiable for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Since
$$\lim_{h\to0^{-}}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a+e^{h}-b-1}{h}$$
and
$$\lim_{h\to0^{+}}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}=2b$$
therefore
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a+e^{h}-b-1}{h}=2b$$
How do I conclude it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^h = 1 + h + o(h)$, so your last equation implies $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \left(\frac{a - b}{h} + 1 + o(1)\right) = 2b$.

There are limits of the second and the third terms, so for limit of sum to exist the first term should also have limit. But it has limit only if $a - b = 0$ - so we geet $a = b$. Substituting, we get that limit is equal to $1$, thus $2b = 1$.

Finishing, we have $a = b = \frac{1}{2}$.